# How to call a function in an HTML doc from an external jQuery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I need help on the logic and method to run a function in a html doc after a function in an external js (jQuery) file has run.

I have two external jQuery files. Both create tables but timesheet_test.js does much more than just this. timesheet_my_table_test.js (creates table 1) and timesheet_test.js (creates table 2).

Table 1 has cells that run a function in the html document when clicked.

e.g.

```
.append('<td class="earlyshift" onclick="setShift(this.className)"></td>')
```

The function:

```
function setShift(className) {
  // Gets the workday shift from the localStorage.
  const targetStateValue = localStorage.getItem('shiftstatus');

  // The logic for updating the value.
  if (targetStateValue === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('shiftstatus', className);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('shiftstatus', className);
  }
}
```

timesheet_test.js then runs a function when clicking on the table header (in table 2), the actions of which depends on which cell was last clicked in table 1, above.

e.g.

Mousedown:

```
if (targetStateValue === "earlyshift") {
  var startCell = [0,curColHead.data("col")];
  isColSelecting = true;
  startSelecting(ev,startCell);
}
```

Mouseup:

```
if (targetStateValue === "earlyshift") {
  var endCell = [14,curColHead.data("col")];
  var correctedCells = cellCompare(operationArea.startCell,endCell);
  afterSelecting(ev,correctedCells);                        
}
```

The end result of this function is it changes the background color in table 2 (which is currently set in css), for cell 0 to cell 14 in the selected column.

I then want to run another function, that is in the html document (without adding any more buttons to click).
I currently have to click a button to run it and want to do away with the button (it already takes between 2 and 3 table clicks to complete the process).
I want it to execute after the Mouseup event, above:

The function is far from complete but is working as is.
When complete it will change the icon/image (which is currently set in css), in the corresponding cell that started this process:

```
$("#J_timingSubmit2").click(function(ev){

  var sheetStates = sheet.getSheetStates();
  var rowsCount = 15;
  var colsCount = 7; //currently not used but want to use it in testData.match below.
  var timesheetrowsdata = "";
  var timesheetcoldata = "";

  for(var row= 0, rowStates=[]; row<rowsCount; ++row){
    rowStates = sheetStates[row];
    timesheetrowsdata += rowStates+(row==rowsCount-1?'':',');
  }

  timesheetcoldata = timesheetrowsdata.replace(/,/g, '');

  const testData = timesheetcoldata;
  const dataArr = testData.match(/.{1,7}/g)
  .map(s => Number(s[0]))

  let dataSum = dataArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  let isSameAsRowsCount = dataSum == rowsCount;

});
```

This is the working button code (that successfully runs the function above):

```
<button class="J_sheetControl" id="J_timingSubmit2">Submit</button>
```

How do I translate that button code so I can run the function form the other js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor your code so that you have a "library" javascript file. then include that file on both pages.

EDIT: This simulates the sort of thing I was trying to explain. Each `<script>` tag would be seperate files though, but it works in the same way.

If the "library js file" contains only functions it should be fine to put it anywhere on the page as JavaScript will cache all of the function and class stuff and allow you to use it anywhere, however, if you declare variables in the library file then make sure to put it above the actual javascript.

If your code still doesn't work after that then there is probably something wrong with your code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //library file
            var test = "hello world!";
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //code
            console.log(test);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this mean to create a js file? I tried that and then get errors that ReferenceError: sheet is not defined (and others). This is the same as when I tried to include the code in the existing js file. I have tried to google my solution but all I can find is how to call a js file from an html doc, not the other way around.

Comment: @flakie I have updated my answer, I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: You should put code into file and refer it with <script type="text/javascript" src="http://host/path/file.js"></script> to include it in your html file. @glend example show you how it works if you have two file where one refer variable defined in an other

Comment: Thanks, So if I put one part of a script (that has multiple functions) into a js file, I have to put all the script in it, with all the functions? I just wonder why the original developers never put this 60 lines of code into their js file which has about 600+ lines of code.

Comment: @flakie you might not need to put all of the functions in, just the ones that are used in multiple places

Comment: Ok thanks. Will check it out. For sure I wont be able to put the php echo code in.

Comment: @flakie you can do a similar thing in PHP using `include` https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: so to call the function that is now in a js file I just write the function name. e.g. ColumnChecker()  -  But I then get ColumnChecker is not defined. Maybe it is the order the js are loaded? But if I move one it will likely break the other. Guess I am going to have to create multiple js files (I already load 5).

Comment: @flakie no, as I explained the JavaScript interpreter pre-scans for functions and class definition. The order shouldn't matter for functions.

Comment: Yes, I still get the error no matter what order I load the js files. So I am calling the function correctly? Just specify function name and the brackets?  -  ColumnChecker()

Comment: @flakie yes. There is something wrong with the code.

Comment: I don't understand why though. It works fine in the html file when called from a button. Moved it to a js file and now it does not work from the button or from the table header (which is how I want it to work). Guess I might as well just move it all back how it was and use the button.

Comment: @flakie post the JavaScript files.

Comment: Some are a bit large so maybe not a good idea. Anyway to test I just renamed the function to what it was originally. Then set the button up back how it was. Now I get no error message. But the button does nothing. Will setup the debugger and have a look but I think I am just going to give up. All this time to just save a button click probably is not worth it.

Comment: Hold it. Typo. used a 3 instead of a 2. Renamed to how it was originally, the function works from the js. But still unable to get it to work from the second js file on table header click. How do I call this function? I will post button code and function name in original question.

Comment: @flakie yes. Though, I would prefer it if it were in a JSFiddle.

Comment: I am going to post a new question for this as, although related to this question, I think it is a new topic? No idea how to do a JSFiddle though.